# How to register the wsgi if the python-socketio is a part of my project

Tags: python, django, socket.io, python-socketio

I am reading the [python-socketio example](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/tree/master/examples/wsgi/django_example).

in its `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from socketio import Middleware

from socketio_app.views import sio

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_example.settings")

django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)
```

in the `views.py`:

```
async_mode = None

import os

from django.http import HttpResponse
import socketio

basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sio = socketio.Server(async_mode=async_mode)
thread = None
```

I want to know, the GitHub example shows use this method to register wsgi application:

```
django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)
```

But in my project, the `python-socketio` is a part of it, how can I register the `wsgi` in this scenario?

I mean I want to make the `python-socketio` application to be a part of my project, as a `app` in project. But I don't know how to configure the `wsgi`.

---

**EDIT-01**

My project `wsgi.py` current code is bellow:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Qiyun02.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figure out the way to configure it:

in the `wsgi.py`, configure the `eventlet` like bellow, I solve this issue.

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Qyun.settings")

from socketio import Middleware
from website_chat.views import sio
django_app = get_wsgi_application()
application = Middleware(sio, django_app)

import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), application)
```

Comment: How run can i run it using Gunicorn because when we run it via this command : gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application then It goes like this  [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-01 19:42:53 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (11)
[2022-07-01 19:42:53 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-01 19:42:53 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
(13) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:8001 ???? Here you can see it runs server on two port and serving page on wsgi endpoint